# How do I replace every placeholder picture with corresponding video?

Tags: javascript, replace, dom-events

So I am trying to create a grid of videos in which the "placeholder" picture is replaced by a video next to it in DOM on click.

The code I have written works well if there is one picture/video, but there should be 6. I have tried working through the array of placeholders (with for (let i...)), but then the way I have identified the "video" const with nextElementSibling seems to stop working. Or maybe something else is wrong, I am not sure.

I don't think forEach will help me here, at least as far as I understand how to use it.

One item in the grid looks like this:

```
<div class="videography__content--item">
  <p class="video__title">Ноель Гоеман - Sanctus</p>
  <div class="video__placeholder--container">
     <img src="img/videography/noel-goemanne-sanctus.jpg" alt="" class="placeholder">
     <div class="play-button"></div>
  </div>
  <iframe class="video-insert" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/BkRqCCkUku0" 
title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; 
clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

And this is my JS code:

```
(function () {
  const placeholder = document.querySelector(".video__placeholder--container");
  const video = placeholder.nextElementSibling;

  placeholder.addEventListener("click", switchToVideo);

  function switchToVideo() {
    placeholder.style.display = "none";
    video.style.display = "block";
  }
})();
```

I am sure there is some simple way to do it, but I am new to JS, so your help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Please add the relevant corresponding HTML.

Comment: @ScottMarcus sorry, added it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with this code:

```
     (function () {
  const arrPictures = document.querySelectorAll(".video__placeholder--container");
  const arrVideos = document.querySelectorAll(".video-insert");

  arrPictures.forEach(function (el, index) {
    el.addEventListener('click', () => switchToVideo(el, index))
  });

  function switchToVideo(el, index) {
    el.style.display = "none";
    arrVideos[index].style.display = "block";
  }
})();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).